# How to retrieve a PowerShell PSCustomObject's properties in its original order

Tags: powershell-5.0

Let's say I have a `PSCustomObject` (I am using PowerShell V5.1):

```
$c = [PSCustomObject]@{name='jeff'; age='40'; dbo='19780101'};
```

If just type `$c`, I will see the following

[image]

Note the **sequence** of the property is: name, age, dbo.

My question is how I can get the properties of `$c` in its original order?

If I try the following, the sequence is totally different (i.e. in ascii seq).

```
$c | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty
```

[image]

What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Get-Member` shows the properties in alphabetic order. You can use the intrinsic member `PSObject`, though:

```
$c.PSObject.Properties | Select-Object Name, MemberType, TypeNameOfValue, Value
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Ansgar, that's exactly what I need !